# Why a neutral point of charge can't produce lines of forces

Tags: electrostatics

In electrostatics,  there is a quantity called "lines of force" which is a hypothetical concept. This concept describes; lines are directed out from positive charges and directed inward to negative charges showing the direction of the electric field.

But my question is, can a line of force be terminated on a neutral point charge?

Why a neutral point charge can not produce lines of forces?

Why only positive and negative charges are able to form electric fields?

Comment: *"Why a neutral point charge can not produce lines of forces?"* - If a *positive* charge is a *source* of field lines while  a *negative* charge is a *sink* for field lines, then a zero (neutral) charge is *neither* a source or a sink for field lines since it 'sits on the boundary' between source and sink.

Answer (score 4):

Lines of force are a useful visual aid which give information about the direction of the electric field at a point (tangent to field line) and the strength of the electric field (density of field lines).

If there is no net electric field at a point there cannot be a field line.  However it is just a point and there will be electric field lines around it.

I am afraid that I cannot answer your last question about the origin of electric fields.

Answer (score 2):

A neutral charge is not another kind of charge. It is no charge at all!

Lines of force only start on +ve charges and end on -ve charges. They don't start or end on things which are not charges (ie neutral materials), but they can pass through them.